# Visibility settings for profile fields

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Can we have visibility options (such as being visible to anyone, only logged-in users or just you) for our profile fields<sup>1</sup>?

For example, I've always have found it, well, "creepy" that anyone can Google search how long ago I was online, so I would personally hide the "seen" field, but I wouldn't mind displaying my "helpful flags" count (not the link to my actual flagging history).

<sup><sup>1</sup> All fields (i.e, website, age, location, member for, visited, seen, profiles views, helpful flags, email & real name) except for a select few that are compulsory(?).</sup>

Comment: If I fill all the fields out, then set them all to hidden, can I still earn the Autobiographer badge?

Comment: @CodyGray I would assume so, since the badge is for *filling* out your profile. "Completed all user profile fields."

Comment: If a filled-out profile falls in the forest, can anyone read it?

Comment: @CodyGray Huh, what'd you mean?

Comment: It is a reference to the classic philosophical question, if a tree falls in the forest and no one is there to hear it, does it still make a sound? Obviously if I fill out all the fields I earn the badge. But the point was, if I fill them all out and then make them hidden so that no one can see them, does it still *count* that I filled them out?

Comment: @CodyGray Oh, I've never heard of that one before, well maybe some fields could be made compulsory to display (to other SO users) then.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't realise the "Seen" field was visible to everyone.

Comment: @ChrisF Yep it is, just open an "incognito" tab (if you're in Chrome) and view your profile.

Comment: @Sam I did check before making that comment :) I only tend to view profiles on sites where I'm a moderator, so my "normal" view is somewhat distorted.

Comment: Visibility settings would be great, I would prefer to hide my flags though.

Comment: @Payeli I mean, I wouldn't mind displaying my "helpful flags" *count*, but definitely not the actual link to my flagging history, absolutely agree with you on that one.